# Changing Objects Texture in Unity Game Engine Using C# Scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, gameobject

I have two objects, both with different textures and I want to make them the same at a certain point of time. The current code I am looking at is the following:

```
weaponObject.renderer.material.mainTexture = selectedWeapon.renderer.material.mainTexture;
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work. The "weaponObject" texture seems to remain the same but simply moves further backwards in terms of the z axis. Any tips? Both Objects are type GameObject.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the textures fit both `GameObjects`. Pretty much you can't attach the texture of an m4 to an m16, the texture won't align correctly.

You also need to make sure that both objects use the same type of material. Remember a material affects how it will look, so even the same texture on different materials will look different.

Example, same texture with different materials:

[image]

If the two objects are identical, which they should be if you want consistent results, then just swap the materials:

```
weaponObject.renderer.material = NewMaterial;
```